# Why is the marginal continuous pdf of X+Y in this form?

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution

I read in a book that given a joint continuous pdf $g(x+y)$, for $y$ is:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x+y)dx = \int_{y}^{\infty}g(x)dx 
$$

I got stuck here, how did $\int_{y}^{\infty}g(x)dx $ come out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation is bad. Let $z= x + y$. after the transformation you have with respect to $z$ that the integral goes from $y$ to infinity since $x$ goes from 0 to infinity.